# GoogleBot Issues

Tags: wordpress, schema, googlebot

It seems googlebot is not being able to access my WordPress posts suddenly which were top ranking till 5 days back. All three Google Test links below are giving an error.

1. https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgosumitup.com%2Fhealth-benefits-of-cumin-seeds-or-jeera
2. https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgosumitup.com%2Fhealth-benefits-of-cumin-seeds-or-jeera&user_agent=1
3. https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fgosumitup.com%2Fhealth-benefits-of-cumin-seeds-or-jeera

I am using WordPress 5.5.1 running soledad theme.

Would appreciate your help in identifying the issue/s & solving this. I will be happy to provide any more information as needed.

Thank you,
Sumit

Comment: well, If you try your main site            >  https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?id=sZ3ycv2_q_kGOU1oKdbS0A   <                    is not giving any errors so maybe you have exceded the number of requests google permits for a certain page ?

Comment: Have you added any new javascript to that page specifically or new plugins or themes to that page?

Comment: Thanks Angel .. Nothing new has been added. I have been removing unused plugins and identified issues with the removed plugins and cleaning up the code in Wp-config and htaccess. But nothing has helped till now

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, for non-related code questions visit Wordpress Stackexchange @ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com. "... Off-topic questions include those about theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices, server configuration, etc. These are best asked on the dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com)."